# How to customize the UIActivityIndicatorView with the IOS 9 style

Tags: ios, swift

Im trying in swift to customize the activity indicator as the figure I show below but I dont find anything

[image]

and part of my code in the main view controller is:

```js
 @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

  let apiClient = ApiClient()
  var flyers: [Flyer]!
  var events: [Event]!

  let actInd : UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, 50, 50)) as UIActivityIndicatorView

  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    actInd.center = self.view.center
    actInd.hidesWhenStopped = true
    actInd.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge
    actInd.color = UIColor.blackColor()
    view.addSubview(actInd)
    actInd.startAnimating()

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    print("MainController viewWillAppear")

    api.getList() { flyers, error in
      if flyers != nil {
        self.flyers = flyers
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.actInd.stopAnimating()
      } else {
        print("error: \(error)")
      }
    }
  }
```

Any ideas?
thx alot

Comment: check SwiftLoader on github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/TransitApp/SVProgressHUD) framework is an alternative for you. It uses pod to install. [Here](https://cocoapods.org/) is a guide of how to use Cocapods.

Comment: Please include information in your answers, even if it is describing what is linked.